# Trivial databinding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to fill a combobox with an ObservableList or a List object that I get from a method call (GetYears).

ObjectDataProvider looked promising but when I try to use it I get "x:Key is allowed for resources and dictionary elements only" and run into trouble in where I should place it in my xaml.

Currently I do the same thing using the following snippet but I feel this is against WPF best practices and more WinForms.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    YearComboBox.ItemsSource = GetYears();
}...
```

I'm looking at the following pages

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx and this page http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140621/WPF-Tutorial-Concept-Binding
and speed reading the following book "Pro WPF in C# 2010"

My background is more Android/c/c++ - this is my first foray into a .Net/WPF in my quest of learning WPF I have read a few MVVM articles but nothing thorough enough to get the full idea; it's mainly snippets from people who kind-of got it. Anyone have a full MVVM .sln example? Maybe a UML diagram of MVVM? I feel like I need to get a grasp of a big picture to help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ObjectDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is right choice as per your requirement.

Also, as error states you need to `place it under Resource section of root` (which can be anything *Window, UserControl, Grid etc*)

Like mentioned in second article you posted in question (*Small sample*):

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" xmlns:m="clr-namespace:ActualNamespace">

    <StackPanel.Resources>
      <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type m:StringData}"
         x:Key="objStrings" MethodName="GetStrings"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <ComboBox Name="lstStrings" Width="200" Height="300"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource objStrings}}" />

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Will Accept answer unless a better one comes along. Once I get it working; give me till after lunch or 5pm today?

Comment: Ok, try out mate. No problem.!!

Comment: Silly question I'm sure; but what is ObjectType="{x:Type m:StringData}" referring to.. as in - what does it match up with. Class Name? x:Type seems arbitrary.

Comment: `x:Type` is equivalent to `Type` class in C#. `m` is namespace of your class where fetch method resides. `StringData` is class name containing fetch method. You need to map `m` with actual namespace in root element.

Comment: Works. My experience so far with WPF is that it's terrible. :)
Edit: To note why - I feel like the documentation is hard to grasp and extremely inadequate, compared to say, the Android Framework.

Comment: Yeah it takes time to get adapt to it. But when you hold a grasp of it, i am sure you gonna fall in love with it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/ and her blog in general. Once you grasp the basics, I highly recommend the MVVM Light toolkit. http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/